# NSMutableArray empty string ()

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

i have an NSMutableArray that gives this output in the debug area:

```
finalArray  (
        (
    )
)
```

Now i want an if else statement to do something if this is the output. I tryd this:

```
NSArray *emptyArray = @[];
if (finalArray == nil || finalArray == emptyArray)
{
    NSLog(@"foobar");
}
```

How can i check if my array is this output?

Comment: your array has an item and that item is empty

Comment: If you want to check if finalArray is empty use count. Because == compares pointers, finalArray == emptyArray statement will never be true if these objects doesn't point the same address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array consists of another item (probably also an array) which is empty.

To check for that, you can use:

```
if(finalArray.firstObject.count == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"It's empty!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed the code a to this:
if([_finalArray.firstObject count] == 0)
    {}

Answer (score 0):

You can count the items of the array with the following code:

```
if([emptyArray count] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"array is empty");
}
```